# C++ Boost FileSystem temporary path appended with file doesn't exist

Tags: c++

I have a class which accepts a string path in its constructor:

```
class S
{
public:
    S(const std::string& path)
    {
        assert(std::filesystem::exists(path));
    }
};
```

I wish to unit test this, using a path which only temporarily exists.

It seems the only way to create a unique temporary folder is using `boost::filesystem`:

```
TEST(MyTest)
{
    using bf = boost::filesystem;

    const bf::path tempPath = bf::unique_path() /= bf::path("file.txt");

    std::ofstream(tempPath.string(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    S s(tempPath.string());
}
```

However, the assert is triggering because this path doesn't exist.

Am I abusing the usage of this, or is there a correct way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know `boost::filesystem` well but `bf::unique_path() /= bf::path("file.txt");` looks wrong. I would expect `bf::unique_path() / bf::path("file.txt");` or just `bf::unique_path() / "file.txt";` - Edit: Nope. It seems to be the correct way to append to a path in `boost::filesystem`

Comment: You use the unique path as a directory. That directory probably doesn't exist, which means you need to create it first.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought unique_path is to create a unique, temporary directory? I don't want to explicitly create a folder, I just want any temporary folder, put my file in there and it get deleted after the test.

Comment: @user997112 No, only the name. "_The `unique_path` function generates a path name suitable for creating temporary files, including directories_"

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh.... is there a way to create a temp directory, which will clean itself up, like Python Temporary Directories?

Comment: @user997112 I haven't read that far yet :-) If not - just encapsulate it in a RAII class. Edit: I get a headache every time I try reading `boost` documentation. :-/ I'd make a wrapper to remove the file after use.